# Generated Files, placed in the obj directory

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that Generates files derived from json for performance before the build occurs, and places them in a folder
obj/Generated Files/SDK.Generator/

This occurs at build time and all the files are building correctly and compile fine. (Tested by dragging them into another project).

In the project that contains the generated files I now need to reference and use those objects.
I get a reference not found error message and the project fails to compile.

> The type or namespace name 'LandingPageOGT' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Check everything into source control and another developer pulls it down and it compiles just fine. (Gets the error but because the files are in the obj folder the project still builds).

I am assuming this is an issue with how my IDE is configured. Since others can build.  Any idea what setting I switched to build makes me build more strictly than the other IDE.

Visual Studio Version *Version 16.11.0 Preview 3.0*

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to delete .vs folder or re-include these file into your project?